# Mule - Returning in JSON and XML on runtime..?

Tags: xml, json, dynamic, mule

In Mule, currently I am using a custom transformer "JavaObjectToJSON" (as a Response Transformer) to convert a POJO to JSON i.e. my component class returns a Java Object (*List* or *HashMap*) and this transformer converts it into JSON and returns the result.

My code is like :

```
<flow name="OfferingDetails">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:1212/jcore/offering/details" 
transformer-refs="HttpParams" responseTransformer-refs="JavaObjectToJSON">  
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <component class="main.java.com.raman.jcore.OfferingDetails"/>
</flow>
```

Now Suppose I want to return the result in XML. For this i can use another custom transformer "JavaObjectToXML" that can do the same in similar manner.

---

But my query how can i do this **dynamically**. Like if i give choice to Client on how it wants the data. And he can hit the URL like

- "http://localhost:1212/jcore/offering/details/?response=json"
- "http://localhost:1212/jcore/offering/details.json/"

OR

- "http://localhost:1212/jcore/offering/details/?response=xml"
- "http://localhost:1212/jcore/offering/details.xml/

And so i would be able to change the transformer at ***runtime***, and return the result in corresponding notation. Is there any way to do it..??

or apart from Changing Transformer, any other workaround ??

Please Help me. I am Stuck in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a choice routing message processor to select the right transformer in the response phase.

Something in the line of:

```
<flow name="OfferingDetails">
  <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:1212/jcore/offering/details"
                         transformer-refs="HttpParams" />  

  <component class="main.java.com.raman.jcore.OfferingDetails"/>

  <response>
    <choice>
      <when expression="message.getInboundProperty('http.request.path').contains('json')" evaluator="groovy">
        <transformer ref="JavaObjectToJSON" />
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <transformer ref="JavaObjectToXML" />
      </otherwise>
    </choice>
  <response>
</flow>
```

Comment: Hey I used this Code. I got an Error saying : ..

Element 'transformer-refs' should contain an attribute ">" or "/>" ...So i did some Hit and Trial and got the Answer...Your code really helped...Thanks..!!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you've worked out a valid solution from my untested sample :)